# Specify which config transform to use for continuous deployment to Azure web app

Tags: asp.net, azure

Is there a way to specify which config transform should be applied when deploying to an Azure web app through continuous integration (i.e. not through *Publish* in Visual Studio)?

We have continuous integration set up with Github, but it seems the **Web.Release.config** transform is always applied on deployment.

We would prefer to have a custom transform name, e.g. **Web.Azure.config**.

Is *deployment slots* used for this? And if so, is that the *only* way to do it?

Thanks!

PS. Does this question belong on ServerFault? I think it's more related to programming? DS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The environment name can be set for a specific Azure web app by adding an application setting, in the Azure portal, called **SCM_BUILD_ARGS** with a value of **-p:Environment MyAzureSite**

This will set the environment name, resulting in a config transform named **Web.MyAzureSite.config** to be applied during build.

More information [here](http://brian.vallelunga.com/blog/chaining-azure-web-config-transforms-when-deploying-from-source-control)

Comment: As the link doesn't open from the answer, [here](http://brian.vallelunga.com/blog/chaining-azure-web-config-transforms-when-deploying-from-source-control) it is

Comment: Also it's good to clarify here that "Environment" is not something built-in in MSBuild, but a custom attribute that ca used in an AfterBuild config transformation.

Comment: For me the above value threw an error, this worked: /p:Environment="MyAzureSite"

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you might consider is whether that configuration setting is appropriate for the web.config file whether it might be better managed in the Web App configuration inside of Azure. Any AppSettings managed in the portal will override anything in the web.config file.

See here for guidance: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Managing-settings-and-secrets

However, to answer your question, the Azure Continuous Deploy uses the Kudu build process. The msbuild command that is passed to build your project on azure (after you git push/github pull) is something like:

```
MSBuild MyWebApp\MyWebApp.csproj /t:pipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder /p:_PackageTempDir="%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%";AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=false;Configuration=Debug;SolutionDir="%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%"
```

This step does web.config transformation too.  To customize deployment like the way you would like you might want to also take a look at:

https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment-hooks

Comment: Thanks for your help! Are you saying Azure is doing the building of Github repos using Kudu? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: I tried generating a deployment script with azure-cli. However, this would mean that my deploy.cmd would control the configuration name for all deployments. I would basically want one transform to be applied in the staging environment, and another one in the production environment - both being deployed from the same repo.

Comment: So in response to your first comment...Yes, Azure is using Kudu as the engine to do automated git (and hg) deployments. Ultimately, it calls a webhook that does the MSBuild line in the answer above.

Comment: In response to your second comment: This is where you would look at deployment hooks for customizing individual deployments. Do you only have a single repository branch that you are deploying to staging and production with only one commit? If so, you might consider the deployment slots and only deploy your code to one slot and then VIP swap the into production without redeploying code. You can see a quick video I put together on this here: [link](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/raw-tech/Continuous-Deployment-to-an-Azure-Web-App-Deployment-Slot)

Comment: However, after looking at your other answer, using "SCM_BUILD_ARGS" looks like it is much easier. I learned something new.

Comment: Yeah, it seems to work fine! Deployment slots is normally an option, but in this case the environments are in different Azure subscriptions.